# Subset list based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(area = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 
2L), .Label = c("DE1", "DE3", "DE4", "DE5", "DE9", "DEA", "DEB", 
"DEC"), class = "factor"), to.delete = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("area", "to.delete"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I want to create a list of the areas which have a '1' in the 'to'delete' column.  I know how to subset the 1s out of this dataframe, however I want the list of areas as eventually I will use this list to extract these areas from the main master data file (df2, listed below).

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = 1:24, area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DE1", "DE3", "DE4", "DE5", "DE9", 
"DEA", "DEB", "DEC"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "area"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

I prefer to do this in two steps, so I can easily see which areas I have deleted (thanks to answers below for suggestions of using list).

```
a <- list(df$area[df$to.delete == 1])
df2.subset <- df2[df2$area %in% a,]
```

This however doesn't seem to work at the moment, so if anyone has any ideas, then that would be great.

df2 should then be left with only areas DE5, DEC and DE3.

Many thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output would be.  Can you post the expected also.  Perhaps, `subset(mainfile, area %in% df$area[df$to.delete==1])`

Comment: @Many thanks akrun, I have now added further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another method using `split` to collect the areas into two lists:

```
# get two lists of areas and give list items appropriate names
keepDrop <- setNames(split(df$area, df$to.delete), c("drop", "keep"))

# now perform dropping
df2.smaller <- df2[df2$area %in% keepDrop[["keep"]],]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset`.  Based on the description, the OP wants to `subset` the rows of a main data ('maindata') based on the 'area' that corresponds to 1 in 'to.delete' column.  In that case, we extract the 'area' (`df$area[df$to.delete ==1]`) and with `%in%` we subset the 'maindata'.

```
subset(maindata, area %in% df$area[df$to.delete==1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear what you are asking.

This will create a list where each element is a different Area:

```
lapply(df$area[df$to.delete == 1], function(x) x)
```

If you want a list with just one element containing all the areas:

```
list(df$area[df$to.delete == 1])
```

Edit:
To answer the second part of your question:

```
a <- list(df$area[df$to.delete == 1])
df2.subset <- df2[!df2$area %in% a[[1]], ]
```

Comment: Thanks @thepule - but how do I then use this to exclude these areas from my master df (df2 in new edited question)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try .

```
a <- as.list(subset(df,df$to.delete == 1)) 


> a
$area
[1] DE1 DE4 DE9 DEB DEA
Levels: DE1 DE3 DE4 DE5 DE9 DEA DEB DEC

$to.delete
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```